# How to Set constraints for UILabels programmatically Where Label Count is equal to Main screen Height in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3, constraints

I would like to create this Format

```
label 1 | label 2 | label 3 | label 4
label 5| label 6| label 7|
```

where labels Count is equal to View Height. and want to set constraints also. 
The code below is the Create UILabels:

```
for i in 0...Int(self.view.frame.height)
{
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
    label.text = "label"
    label.sizeToFit()
    self.view.addSubview(label)
}
```

Comment: why don' t you use `UIStackView`

Comment: Use tableview and use Int(self.view.frame.height) in numberOfRows

Comment: hello @JonSnow I don't want to use any Content. Need to perform in Basic way..Thanks

Comment: @Sgr , If your app supports ios 9 + then it is very easy with stackView

Comment: @RajeshkumarR i Don't want to use tableView or collectionView. i want to do this with NSLayoutConstraint only

Answer (score 1):

It looks you want to stack 4 labels in each row.

If you support iOS > 9.0, use `UIStackView`.

Otherwise, you have to calculate the spacing between the labels for each row:

```
let spacing = (screenWidth -  (w1 + w2 + w3+ w4))/5
```

And add the constraints programmatically with `.addConstraints`.

Answer (score 0):

The better way to do it is by using Visual format language but I can't help you out with an answer with context to VFS because I personally don't use it.

But if you want to do it with NSLayoutConstraint then it can be done in a very easy way.

I am not writing the exact code but would explain to you how you have to deal this out.

Note - Don't forget to set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`
and Don't forget to set isActive = true on all the constraints which you want to keep active.

because if you forget to do it then your code won't work

Then align left `label1` to the parent view you can either do this by anchors or NSLayoutConstraints I would recommend doing it with Anchor.

```
label1.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
```

Then align other label's leading edge to the trailing edge of the previous one like -

```
label2.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label1.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
```

and finally, align the rightmost label to the trailing edge of parent view like -

```
rightMostLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentView.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
```

Then set the top alignment of the label1 with respect to the parent view

```
label1.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentView.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
```

Then finally set the width of all the labels equal to any one of the label. Let's say, we set the width of all the labels equal to label1.
by-

```
NSLayoutConstraint(item: label1, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: label2, attribute: .width, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).isActive = true
```

This code above was with label1 and label2 you would have to do it again with label2 and label3 and so on.